# tax_input argument for wp_insert_post()

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm trying to insert custom taxonomies using `wp_insert_post()` and the `tax_input` argument, but it doesn't work. I want to set a post to a custom taxonomy ('types') and a category ('cars')

```
$new_post = array(

        'post_title'    =>   $title,

        'post_content'  =>   $description,

        'tax_input' =>   array('types' => array('cars')),  

        'post_status'   =>   'pending',          

        'post_type' =>   'vehicles'  

        );
```

Comment: where are you trying to use this? if the current user doesn't have permission to assign terms in that taxonomy, it will fail.

Comment: Everything else, except that line of 'tax_input' goes perfectly. I test it as admin, so maybe that is not the problem :/ ?

Comment: Is "cars" a _category_ or a _term_ in your custom taxonomy?

Comment: I guess it's a term. My custom taxonomy is called 'types' and my categories are as followed: cars, trucks, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the answer. After building my arguments for wp_insert_post() function and passed it to a variable $pid i set the following line after that and everything works slightly.

```
wp_set_object_terms($pid, 'cars', 'types', true);
```